# MacBook Pro 11,3 message: unplug the accessory using too much power to reenable usb devices

Tags: macbook-pro

MacBook Pro 11,3 message: "unplug the accessory using too much power to reenable usb devices"

How do I get more power to the usb?

Comment: You don't. It's saying that whatever you plugged in is trying to draw more power than the Mac can handle. The device is either defective or not compatible with your Mac.

Comment: Or you connect the USB device to a hub that can supply enough power but the previous comment is probably correct - You caoul ask a question about connecting the device to a Mac giving details of the device

Comment: Another possibility is that the USB cable that you are using has a short in it and that is causing the extra power draw. Yes, it sounds odd but it has happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't.

The mere fact that you are seeing the message means that the MacBook Pro's USB port cannot support the amount of power required by the device.

As [mmmmmm](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237/mmmmmm) said in his comment, it may be possible to plug it into an externally powered USB hub that can also plug into your Mac. **However, if a device uses too much power for your Mac's USB ports, there is no way around it.**

Comment: I used a powered hub and it didn't solve the issue with a CoolerMaster MM730 mouse. I get the error message randomly when waking up my MBP.